# Install amazonmp3 on a 64-bit desktop

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, amazon-mp3-downloader

Try to install amazonmp3 on a ubuntu desktop 64bit edition. Amazon only supports Ubuntu 8.10 32Bit version. 
I googled around to see if there was a way to install 32 bit packages under 64 bit Ubuntu, I ran into http://www.ensode.net/roller/dheffelfinger/entry/installing_amazon_mp3_downloader_under (using **getlibs**).

But there are some missing libs

*No* match for libboost_filesystem-gcc42-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
*No* match for libboost_regex-gcc42-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
*No* match for libboost_date_time-gcc42-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
*No* match for libboost_signals-gcc42-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
*No* match for libboost_iostreams-gcc42-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
*No* match for libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1

Is there a way to install amazonmp3 on a 64bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to take a look at [this Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9145072&postcount=17) posting - though it is written for 10.04.

However there are alternatives to installing this package from Amazon: there are alternatives to the Amazon MP3 Downloader. [Pymazon](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/pymazon-amazon-mp3-download-replacement.html) is an option, and there is also now a [Banshee extension](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/amazon-mp3-download-extension-for.html) to do the job.

Comment: Now amazonmp3 is installed (Installing these missing dependencies manually through getlibs will make them available to the amazonmp3 binary) - but I will try the alternatives

Comment: Seriously, Banshee with the Amazon extension is the way of least pain.

Answer (score 4):

**Install Clamz from the Ubuntu Software Center**

Just went to the "Ubuntu Software Center" and looked up amazon and noticed there was a program called "Clamz" says that it's for downloading mp3 from amazon.

**what I did**

1. Installed [clamz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clamz) 
   from the Ubuntu Software Store
2. Purchased the album I wanted from Amazons site - One click download link
3. Amazon sent me a link with an amz extension
4. Opened the amz file and a terminal window opened and I was downloading

Not the pretties, but really awesome!